# Patenting same idea with different methodology

Tags: patent-search, idea, illegal, methodology

I had a key idea to StartUp a company. But I found other company already holding a patent(found in Google patent search) on same idea but different approach to accomplish it.

Can I patent the same idea with my own methodology? Is it illegal to use an idea which is already patented?

Comment: When you say "same idea but different approach" do you mean accomplishes the same goal but uses a different technique?

Comment: same idea = same goal + same data collection but processing on data is different.

Comment: Atsby answer then is a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I patent the same idea with my own methodology?

You can obtain a patent incorporating the same idea as long as your own methodology is a non-obvious improvement over the prior art (including but not limited to that specific competitor's patent). The claims will have to include some of the methodology details to render them non-obvious.

> Is it illegal to use an idea which is already patented?

Ideas themselves cannot be patented. It is an act of infringement to practice a patented invention, as defined by its claims and the relevant statutes governing patent infringement. Patent infringement is not a criminal offense. At most, you would be liable for monetary damages and you may have to cease operations if a patent holder obtains an injunction against you.

As always, you should consult a patent attorney who can look at all the details of your situation.

Comment: so if i have a same idea regarding my own methodology i cant apply for patent?and even this type of idea with my own methodology patent is not available in my country...so what can i do now?

Comment: @indirajith  The use of the term "idea" is ambiguous. For instance an idea might be to seal a bottle of wine. One technique might be a cork and another might be a screw top. Each is its own implementation, but both address the same need.